# Difficulty in understanding the role of the projection function in the context of definition of cartesian product of sets and choice function.

Tags: set-theory

For the following definition having to do with the cartesian product of sets and the axiom of choice.

> A cartesian product of the family $(A_i|i\in I)$ of sets is the set
> $$\prod_{i\in I}A_i=\{f|f:I\rightarrow\cup_{i\in I}A_i \text{with } f(i)\in A_i \text{ for each } i\in I\}$$
> together with the projections $\pi_{j}:\prod_{i\in I}A_i\rightarrow A_j,$ $f\leftrightarrow f(j)$
> Note: $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ denotes the cartesian product of sets $A_i$.

I just want to make sure if I understand how the projection function is used here.
$\pi_{j}$ projectects $f$ down to a specific index $j$.  Whenever I see the choice function $f:I\rightarrow\cup_{i\in I}A_i$, I automatically think that the function $f$ simultaneously chooses an $i$ so that $f(i)\in A_i$ if the index $I$ is an infinite set. Also I don't really understand the notation: $\pi_{j}:\prod_{i\in I}A_i\rightarrow A_j,$ $f\leftrightarrow f(j)$?  Also, should it be $f\rightarrow f(j)$ and not $f\leftrightarrow f(j)$. Can someone tell me if my understanding is correct.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes. $\pi_i$ maps $f$ to $f(i)$. Think of $f(i)$ as the $i$th co-ordinate of $f$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thank you for clarificying that for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your first question. The function $f$ is giving a choice for every index in $I$. If the set $I$ is infinite you are using the axiom of choice, but there is no other problem...

On the other hand, it should be
$$
\begin{array}{r}
\pi_{i}:\prod_{i\in I}A_i\rightarrow A_i\\
f \mapsto f(i)
\end{array}
$$

I don't see where your $j$ comes from.

Comment: I edited the question, the line where the projection function appears now reads:  $\pi_{j}:\prod_{i\in I}A_i\rightarrow A_j,$ $f\leftrightarrow f(j)$